# Why does finfo_buffer() return not the same mime-type as mime_content_type()?

Tags: php

I tried to detect the mime-type of an uploaded MSWord document in “doc” format, but `finfo_buffer()` returned `application/octet-stream`, while `mime_content_type()` returned `application/msword`, which is more specific. Why is this happening and is there any way to detect the mime-type correctly without saving the file on a disk (which is required for mime_content_type() since it works only with file paths but not buffers)?